# Importing a markdown file within an Angular library

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library, readme

I am currently trying to import a .md (markdown) file within my Angular library so I can create a method to pass a readme file as a string back to whatever application implements my library.

I have already got this working in a standard application by creating a global.d.ts file in the src folder and giving it the following content:

```
declare module '*.md';
```

I am then able to import the markdown in my app.component.ts file using the following:

```
import * as pageMarkdown from 'raw-loader!../../projects/ui/login/assets/1.md';
```

This works as expected. However, I then try to do the same import in an Angular library I have generated using:

```
ng generate library example-library
```

If I then browse to the component typescript within that library and add the same import it doesn't work. Whenever I build the library I get the following error:

**Cannot find module 'raw-loader!../../projects/ui/login/assets/1.md' or its corresponding type declarations.**

Its almost as if it can't pick up whats declared within my global.d.ts when i'm adding the import to a library. Am I missing something?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you place markdown files in the assets folder or in a docs and expose it like an assets folder. Here is a service i created that renders markdown using marked and highlight.js

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {firstValueFrom, from, Observable, of} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MarkdownConverterService {

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  convert(resourceRelUrl: string): Observable<string> {
    const parseMarkdown: Promise<string> = this.getMarkdownByPath(resourceRelUrl)
      .then(this.parseMarkdown)
    return from(parseMarkdown);
  }

  private async parseMarkdown(markdownString: string) {
    const marked = require('marked');
    const hljs = require('highlight.js');
    marked.setOptions({
      renderer: new marked.Renderer(),
      highlight: function (code: any) {
        return hljs.highlightAuto(code).value;
      },
      langPrefix: 'hljs language-', // highlight.js css expects a top-level 'hljs' class.
      pedantic: false,
      gfm: true,
      breaks: false,
      sanitize: false,
      smartLists: true,
      smartypants: false,
      xhtml: true
    });
    let html$ = of(marked.parse(markdownString));
    return await firstValueFrom(html$)
      .then(value => value.toString());
  }

  private async getMarkdownByPath(path: string): Promise<string> {
    // @ts-ignore
    let markdown$ = this.httpClient.get<string>(path, {responseType: "text"});
    return await firstValueFrom(markdown$)
      .then(value => value.toString());
  }

}
```